# How to store data from pointer returned by strtok into struct without it being lost?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a malloced string that I needed to parse. I did all of the parsing using `strtok()`. `Strtok` has returned a pointer to me and if I `printf` using that pointer the correct part of the parsed string gets printed. Afterwards I will be freeing the malloced string that the pointer returned by `strtok` was pointing too.

How do I store what the pointer was pointing at into a struct such that the value remains in the struct variable even after the main string has been freed.

String: `Tommy-1234567`

My `strtok` return pointer:

```
char *studentName= strtok(String1,"-");
char *studentNo= strtok(NULL,"-");
```

My struct:

```
typedef struct Student{
    char *name;  //Want name to be stored here even after string is freed
    int  *studentNumber;  //Want no. to be stored here even after string is freed
}Student;
```

Comment: How about `strdup(studentName)`?

Comment: By using `strdup`. You don't `free` the (string) pointer returned by `strtok`: it points to a fragmented part of the *string you passed to it*. The only thing you free, is the original string pointer (if it was `malloc`ed) or the fragment pointers (if they were `strdup`ed).

Comment: @WeatherVane im sorry if I explained badly, but yes, I was reffering to freeing the malloced string.

Comment: Sorry if I explained it badly. `strdup` will allocate more memory for, and copy the fragment of the parsed string.You can then `free` the original string. Later, when you have finished with the `student` struct, you can free the pointer that was stored in `student.name`.

Comment: It's not useful to have a pointer for `student.studentNumber`. Since the data is `int` that's more complicated than just storing the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example about the use of `strdup`, the program makes copies of the data obtained from `strtok`. The original string can then be `free`ed

The code posted has a mistake trying to assign a `char*` pointer to `int*`. In C, a textual number is not automatically converted to `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student{
    char *name;
    int  studentNumber;
} Student;

int main(void)
{
    char *string;
    char *tok;
    Student acolyte;

    // set up the input, like this to show use of `strdup` and `free`
    string = strdup("Tommy-1234567");       // allocate memory for source string
    if (string == NULL)                     // check it worked
        return 1;                           // failure

    // student name
    tok = strtok(string, "-");              // isolate first token
    if (tok == NULL)                        // check it worked
        return 1;                           // failure
    acolyte.name = strdup(tok);             // allocated mem for substring and copy
    if (acolyte.name == NULL)               // check it worked
        return 1;                           // failure

    // student number
    tok = strtok(NULL, "-");                // isolate next token
    if (tok == NULL)                        // check it worked
        return 1;                           // failure
    if (sscanf(tok, "%d", &acolyte.studentNumber) != 1)     // extract int
        return 1;                           // failure

    free(string);                           // can now get rid of source data

    // show result
    printf("Name: %s\n", acolyte.name);
    printf("Number: %d\n", acolyte.studentNumber);
    free(acolyte.name);                     // free the memory in struct
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Name: Tommy
Number: 1234567
```

Comment: Will i have to free all the pointers I strdup just like I would free any other pointer I malloc?

Comment: Yes, because `strdup` calls `malloc`.

Comment: Sorry I have one more question regarding this. If I have another free function, where I want to free all the strdups that I did. Is there a way to free all the strdups related to that struct. Or do I literally have to do free(tok)...free(acolyte.studentNumber) one by one.

Comment: You have to free the pointers returned by `strdup` one by one. But you must not try to free the pointers returned by `strtok`. They just point to parts of the original string (which is itself freed), they are not allocated memory. That is why you use `strdup`, because the `tok` pointers (and the original string too) will become invalid. In fact, you can see that `tok` gets overwritten by the next use of `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Allocate More Memory

Since you are freeing the string that you parsed, see [man(3) strdup](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/NetBSD/man3/strdup.3.html)

`char *newstring = strdup(oldstring);`

Comment: Will i have to free all the pointers I strdup just like I would free any other pointer I malloc?